# Give color dynamically to the arrows for pagination

Tags: html, css, png

I need to add the 4 typical arrows for pagination, and I'd like to color them dynamically, how to do it?

Regards

Javier

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: How many colors will be used? For what events?

Comment: I don't have anything..I mean, I want to know if someone did it, and how did it, without too much details..

Comment: @user295734, I will catch the color code from the database through a PHP code embedded in the HTML+CSS code.

Comment: Are the arrows images? .gif, .jpeg, .png?

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use some matching UTF-8 chars a give them a color via CSS, for example:

- U+2770: ❰
- U+2771: ❱
- U+25B6: ▶
- U+25BC: ▼

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arrows/list.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm

Another nice example page on using fonts as icons:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/